Some programs are coming up in Chinese even though I have en_US set as my environment
Running Ubuntu 24.04 and KDE. My locale is set to American English first and simplified Chinese second. Most things work right, but some things are in Chinese rather than English. Shell messages, and some programs like gimp, though most programs do come up in English. I've looked a lot online but cannot find where this is being set.
My environment is:
$ echo $LANGUAGE
en_US:zh_CN
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
$
$ localectl
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: (unset)         
   X11 Layout: us
    X11 Model: pc105
$

Other files I've seen referenced include:
/etc/default/locale, which is LANG=en_US.UTF-8, and /etc/locale.conf, which is LANG=en_US.UTF-8
For shell messages I found if I change LANGUAGE not to include zh_CN the messages are in English, but if I add a third language and set LANGUAGE=en_US:zh_CN:en_GB the messages are in Chinese.
Other files I've seen mentioned that could affect things include ~/.pam_environment, which has
LANGUAGE    DEFAULT=en_US:en
LANG    DEFAULT=en_US.UTF-8

and the ~/.kde subtree, which I don't have. Are there any suggestions for where else the language is being stored, and how I can get everything to come up in English?

Check the config of each app that is coming up wrong and make sure it is not an app setting.

Nice thought, but that wouldn't explain the shell error messages. But I did look at GIMP config (~/.config/GIMP/2.10/) and didn't see any reference to LANG with grep -i lang * /
